# Yii2 Class 'url' not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, classnotfound

Please can anybody help me explain what causes Class 'Url' not found in yii2 error I'm having a hard time with it [image]

Comment: Just import Url class (Add `use yii\helpers\Url` on next line after `<php` )

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell PHP about class location in order to use it, if it's not in same directory. add [use yii\helpers\Url](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-url) on top of `index.php` file

**index.php**

```
<?php
 use yii\helpers\Url;
?>
// Rest of the index file code
```